# Display specific word in file. To be used as varible, grep for email in log

Tags: email, ssh, logging, grep, sed

I'm looking to display just the email address in the /var/log/secure file.  The email goes into a variable, so just grepping for lines won't work.

I know how to string together sed commands, but is there a cleaner way?

I could even scrap the idea altogether, if there is a cleaner way to get ssh key comment emails.  I'm looking to find out which email comment, on the clients ssh key, was used to login.  So far I have been using something like this..

```
 ssh root@localhost  "sleep 1 ; tail -1 /var/log/secure | ..."
```

I hope there is a better way, or at least a clean way to display just the email.

Comment: Could you please post an (obfuscated) snippet of your log file? I have nothing on my log about SSH keys (and emails).

Comment: ...forgot to mention, ssh going through a wrapper script that logs those key comment emails.

Comment: I ended up finishing this soon after posting. I found a cleaner way,  I got user info out of LDAP and then did a grep -o for the email.

Comment: I really, should have changed the title, to the more relevant question... but the email is in the variable, so the scripts are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't grep work out for you? It has the `-o` parameter to get only the match. So something like `grep -o " .+@.+ " /var/log/secure` should work. Only work out the expression to just match the email address.

Comment: I actually did the grep a small while after posting.
Since you answered here first, you got the check mark anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matteo mentioned, I've never seen the public key informations in `/var/log/secure` but if you want to display only email address from a text file, you can use `egrep` (for extended regex) with `-o` option, something like this:

```
$ egrep -o '[^ ]+@[^ ]+' input
```

or you must escape the plus if you use `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '[^ ]\+@[^ ]\+' input
```

You can also do it with `sed`:

```
$ sed -nr 's/.* ([^ ]+@[^ ]+).*$/\1/p' input
```